# alert Selected Cells Count by Dragging On A Table

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays

How to alert Selected  Cells Count  by Dragging  On A Table .I have a table here i want to alert the selected table cells count using mouse drag. my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/q35vm6qv/1/

```
<table style="width:300px" id="mytable">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the count like this

```
var count = $('.highlighted').length;
```

When you actually want to trigger it depends on your needs.

Comment: how can i add column span dynamically?